# Using blink(1) with python (on raspbian)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use my [Blink(1)](https://blink1.thingm.com/) lights on my pi.

There seem to be 2 ways to get it to work with python (preferred, because of other python libs I want to use)

- the [old library](https://github.com/todbot/blink1/tree/master/python/alternative_libraries) which works great, but I'd like to know how to "install" it instead of having to copy the files to my project and importing it there (yes, kinda noobish quesiton, sorry)
- the new library that can be installed via pip. This one does not work with python2, only python3. But not with the available python3.2, because a dependency uses u'' strings that seemingly are broken in python3 up to 3.4 or something. I tried manually installing 3.5 but there it failed because of some error initializing the USB.

Can anyone provide me with a "fool and noob-proof" way to get it to work?

Comment: What particular problem are you having? If the old library works great, what is the issue there? You can import python modules from where-ever you want as long as the location is in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: okay thanks. my python is a bit rusty :)